# My For loop in PHP used to iterate an array works on the first loop, but not the second

Tags: php, for-loop

if (isset($_GET['q'])){
                  $q = $_GET['q'];

```
              //variables
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product LIKE '%$q%' OR search LIKE '%$q%'";
              $result = $conn->query($sql);


              //check database
              if($result->num_rows > 0){        
                while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                  $product = $row['product'];
                  $productImage = $row['product_image'];
                  $price = $row['price'];
                  $seller = $row['seller_name'];
                  $sellerImage = $row['seller_image'];
                  $desc = $row['description'];
                  $search = $row['search'];
                  $console = $row['console'];

                  $array = array($product, $price, $productImage);
                  $arrayDesc = array($desc, $sellerImage);



                  if (preg_match('/Game/', $seller)){                    
                    for ($num = 0; $num < 3; $num++) {
                      echo '<div class="tile col-md-4 col-sm-3">';
                      if($num == 0){
                        echo '<div class="tileTitleBox"><h4>' . $array[$num] . '</h4></div>';
                      }
                      if($num = 1){
                        echo '<p class="price">' . $array[$num] . '</p>';
                      }
                      if($num = 2){
                        echo '<img class="tilePic" src="' . $array[$num] . '"/>';
                      }
                      // if($num = 3){
                      //   echo '<div class = "desc"><p>' . $array[$num] . '</p></div>';
                      // }
                      echo '</div>';
                    }//For Iteration Loop - TILE

                    for($count = 0; $count < 2; $count++){
                      echo '<div class="tile-description col-md-4 col-sm-3 hidden">';
                      if($count == 0){
                        echo '<div class="desc"><p>' . $arrayDesc[$count] . '</p></div>';
                      }
                      if($count == 1){
                        echo '<img class="sellerImg" src="' . $arrayDesc[$count] . '"/>';
                      }

                      echo '</div>';
                    }//end for loop - TILE-DESCRIPTION
```

So as you see above, I have one for loop which creates the "tile" and the second which is supposed to create the "tile-description". The first one works well to create a single div with the class of "tile" in which my remaining contents is loaded into the div. But in the second for loop the "desc" dev and the "sellerImg" div are separated. The loop needs to go through the array various times.

Shown Bellow:
[You can see that the "Tile" div contains "tileTitleBox", "price", and "tilePic". But the "tile-description" which is hidden, is separated into two divs. As opposed to holding both elements inside the same div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An8Zg.png)

Comment: You don't need the loops at all.

Comment: FYI: `$num = 1` is an assignment and not a comparison.

Comment: what would be the best way to go through the array?

Comment: I need the array to go through various times. Not just one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

@sam-dufel rightly pointed out you're overwriting the iterator

```
if($num = 1){
```

But in fact you shouldn't use any loops here:

```
  echo '<div class="tile col-md-4 col-sm-3">';
  echo '<div class="tileTitleBox"><h4>' . $array[0] . '</h4></div>';
  echo '<p class="price">' . $array[1] . '</p>';
  echo '<img class="tilePic" src="' . $array[2] . '"/>';
  echo '</div>';

  echo '<div class="tile-description col-md-4 col-sm-3 hidden">';   
  echo '<div class="desc"><p>' . $arrayDesc[0] . '</p></div>';
  echo '<img class="sellerImg" src="' . $arrayDesc[1] . '"/>';
  echo '</div>';
```

Comment: The problem is, I need to go through an array various times over.

Comment: @CarlosHernandez Maybe, but not through any of the arrays you have shown in your example.

Comment: the array needs to be iterated various times over. How would this be achieved?

Comment: In your updated example you're creating those arrays in every loop of the while. The correct answer would be: Don't put the staff in new arrays but just display things from $row.